# Trouble centering Bootstrap image gallery

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-image-gallery

I'm using Bootstrap image gallery found [here](https://blueimp.github.io/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/) and I'm having difficulty centering the thumbnails on the page.

They center fine until I add max-width to the style to limit the amount of thumbnails on one row.

The webpage is [here](http://www.te-al.co.uk/p/abbyjan/) and here is my code:

```
<div id="links" class="text-center div-gallery">
  <a href="http://te-al.co.uk/images/portfolio/abbyjan/gallery/aj1.jpg" title="1" data-gallery> <!-- Image -->
    <img src="http://te-al.co.uk/images/portfolio/abbyjan/thumbnails/aj1t.jpg" class="img-gal-box" alt="1"> <!-- Thumbnail -->
  </a>
  <a href="http://te-al.co.uk/images/portfolio/abbyjan/gallery/aj2.jpg" title="2" data-gallery>
    <img src="http://te-al.co.uk/images/portfolio/abbyjan/thumbnails/aj2t.jpg" class="img-gal-box" alt="2">
  </a>
  <a href="http://te-al.co.uk/images/portfolio/abbyjan/gallery/aj3.jpg" title="3" data-gallery>
    <img src="http://te-al.co.uk/images/portfolio/abbyjan/thumbnails/aj3t.jpg" class="img-gal-box" alt="3">
  </a>
  <a href="http://te-al.co.uk/images/portfolio/abbyjan/gallery/aj4.jpg" title="4" data-gallery>
    <img src="http://te-al.co.uk/images/portfolio/abbyjan/thumbnails/aj4t.jpg" class="img-gal-box" alt="4">
  </a>
  <a href="http://te-al.co.uk/images/portfolio/abbyjan/gallery/aj5.jpg" title="5" data-gallery>
    <img src="http://te-al.co.uk/images/portfolio/abbyjan/thumbnails/aj5t.jpg" class="img-gal-box" alt="5">
  </a>
  <a href="http://te-al.co.uk/images/portfolio/abbyjan/gallery/aj6.jpg" title="6" data-gallery>
    <img src="http://te-al.co.uk/images/portfolio/abbyjan/thumbnails/aj6t.jpg" class="img-gal-box" alt="6">
  </a>
  <a href="http://te-al.co.uk/images/portfolio/abbyjan/gallery/aj7.jpg" title="7" data-gallery>
    <img src="http://te-al.co.uk/images/portfolio/abbyjan/thumbnails/aj7t.jpg" class="img-gal-box" alt="7">
  </a>
  <a href="http://te-al.co.uk/images/portfolio/abbyjan/gallery/aj8.jpg" title="8" data-gallery>
    <img src="http://te-al.co.uk/images/portfolio/abbyjan/thumbnails/aj8t.jpg" class="img-gal-box" alt="8">
  </a>
  <a href="http://te-al.co.uk/images/portfolio/abbyjan/gallery/aj9.jpg" title="9" data-gallery>
    <img src="http://te-al.co.uk/images/portfolio/abbyjan/thumbnails/aj9t.jpg" class="img-gal-box" alt="9">
  </a>
  <a href="http://te-al.co.uk/images/portfolio/abbyjan/gallery/aj10.jpgg" title="10" data-gallery>
    <img src="http://te-al.co.uk/images/portfolio/abbyjan/thumbnails/aj10t.jpg" class="img-gal-box" alt="10">
  </a>
  <a href="http://te-al.co.uk/images/portfolio/abbyjan/gallery/aj11.jpg" title="11" data-gallery>
    <img src="http://te-al.co.uk/images/portfolio/abbyjan/thumbnails/aj11t.jpg" class="img-gal-box" alt="11">
  </a>
  <a href="http://te-al.co.uk/images/portfolio/abbyjan/gallery/aj12.jpg" title="12" data-gallery>
    <img src="http://te-al.co.uk/images/portfolio/abbyjan/thumbnails/aj12t.jpg" class="img-gal-box" alt="12">
  </a>
</div>
```

-CSS

```
.div-gallery {
  max-width: 767px;
}
.img-gal-box {
  padding: 1%;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add margin property:

```
.div-gallery {
    margin: auto;
}
```

This along with fixed width you set earlier will center your gallery.

Answer (score 1):

```
div-gallery {
    padding: 1%;
    max-width: 767px;
    margin: -2% auto 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, my understanding is growing. Am I right in thinking that margin: * * * * equates to margin: -top -right -bottom -left or something similar?

Comment: Yes, @Alex, but there are also other versions with 3 and 2 arguments - see here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_margin.asp